# Show that $f(E-F) \not\subseteq f(E)-f(F)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Can someone help explain this question to me?

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a function and $E \subseteq X$ and $F \subseteq X$. Show that in general:

1) $f(E-F) \not\subseteq f(E)-f(F)$

2) $f(E \bigtriangleup F) \not\subseteq f(E)\bigtriangleup f(F)$

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be closed, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?).

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Consider the map $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto x^2$, let $E$ be the set of positive reals, and let $F$ be the set of negative reals.

Then try to see exactly what makes the example work.